# Migração de projeto feito no Eclipse para o Android Studio - FATAL EXCEPTION

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Fiz a importação é não tive erro, mais quando tento compilar o projeto tenho este problema:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
07-13 15:29:13.786 1380-1380/br.com.sistemaguardiao E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{br.com.sistemaguardiao/main.Main}: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                                                                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                      at main.Main.onCreate(Main.java:47)
                                                                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
                                                                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195) 
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
                                                                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Provavelmente é porque tá faltando alguns arquivos essenciais de um projeto Android, como o AndroidManifest que declara todas a activities do projeto. Tem como você tirar uma shot da pasta do seu projeto?

Comment: Abre o terminal no Android Studio e roda este comando `gradlew -d assembleDebug` ele vai "debugar" a build, as vezes corrige alguns errinhos de importação

Comment: @Memphys, adicionei as imagens, agradeço se poder me ajudar, estou realmente precisa de ajuda neste momento

Comment: @LucasQueirozRibeiro, estou fazendo isso agora mesmo, já posto a resposta, estou com um buraco no estomago! :-)

Comment: Eu faria o que o @LucasQueirozRibeiro sugeriu. Tenta fazer o sync do projeto com o gradle também. Estou sem a IDE agora mas se não me engano fica em project > sync project.

Comment: @Memphys, eu fiz, agora me mostra um erro manifest, neste ponto android:name="main.DeviceListActivity" os demais não mostra erro

Comment: Pelo que eu estou vendo dentro da pasta do seu projeto, não há nenhuma classe com o nome de DeviceListActivity. O AndroidManifest.xml está tentando achar essa classe dentro do pacote main e não consegue pois não existe.

Comment: As vezes a classe ficou em uma pasta errada ou em outro package, edita seu manifest ,apaga essa activity que está dando o erro e começa a digitar de novo, a IDE deve sugerir o arquivo certo (Provavelmente sem o main, só `.DeviceListActivity`)